# disable click in gantt view

Tags: jquery, gantt

I wish to disable any modifications to any of the cells in the lefthand side pane of the Gantt view.

I've tried this CSS

```
.jsgrid-control-text
  {
     -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
    pointer-events: none
  } 

.ms-jsgrid-cell-selected-editable
{
     -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
    pointer-events: none
}
```

And this jQuery

```
  jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").attr('readonly', true);
  jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").css({'-ms-user-select': 'none','user-select': 'none', 'pointer-events': 'none'});

  jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").next('span').attr('readonly', true);
  jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").next('span').css({'-ms-user-select': 'none','user-select': 'none', 'pointer-events': 'none'});


  jQuery("tr[role='gridcell']").next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').css({'-ms-user-select': 'none','user-select': 'none', 'pointer-events': 'none'});
  jQuery("tr[role='gridcell']").next('td').next('td').next('td').css({'-ms-user-select': 'none','user-select': 'none', 'pointer-events': 'none'});

  $("div[id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane']").css({'-ms-user-select': 'none','user-select': 'none', 'pointer-events': 'none'});

  jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").next('span').removeClass("jsgrid-control-text");
```

but have had no luck. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Interestingly I've stopped the click selection when using Chrome 66.0.33, but not IE11

Answer (score 1):

I do surprise myself sometimes!

One line of code seems to do the trick, works for both IE and Chrome.

```
jQuery("td[role='gridcell']").on('mousedown', function() { return false; });
```